# Strogngloop/loopback filter by comparing 2 fields of the same model

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop, loopback

Here is the ***schema*** for **MyModel**

```
"properties": {
"amount": {
  "type": "number"
},
"remaining": {
  "type": "number"
}
```

***I want to  filter items with equal  `amount` & `remaining` properties***

is there some thing like this?

```
 const filter = {where:{'amount':'remaining'}}};
```

Comment: I think there is no direct method to achieve this. You need to execute native sql. Which datasource are you using ?